# How to check are 3 strings equal in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I this is my code, and it is working

```
if (v1 == v2) && (v2 == v3) {
    println("3 strings are equal")
}
```

Is there any other more Swift way to do it ?

My implementation look like C code :-)

Comment: No, in C it would look like `if (strcmp(v1, v2) == 0 ...` :)

Comment: I meant because of &&

Comment: `&&` is a valid Swift operator and has the advantage of "short-circuiting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. That's about as straightforward as it gets. (And an improvement on C and ObjC, too — you can use the `==` operator instead of calling `strcmp` or `isEqual:`.)

If you really want to go nuts with it, you might be able to write `v1 == v2 == v3` if you created a couple of custom `==` operator overloads. (This is left as an exercise for the reader.) But it's probably not worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something cool like this:

```
extension Array {

    func allEqual(isEqual: (T, T) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.count < 2 {
            return true
        }
        for x in self {
            if !isEqual(x, self.first!) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
["X", "Y", "Z"].allEqual(==) // false
["X", "X", "X"].allEqual(==) // true
let one = "1"
var ONE = "1"
var One = "1"
[one, ONE, One].allEqual(==) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension for the string class like this :

```
extension String {
    func allEquals (s1: String, s2: String) {
        (this == s1) && (s1 == s2)
    }
}
```

I didn't compiled it but it should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really swifty, you can check an array of strings to be all equal like this (you could wrap that in an extension, of course):

```
var array = ["test", "test", "test"]
var allEqual = array.reduce(true, combine: { (accum: Bool, s: String) -> Bool in
    accum && s == array[0]
})
```

I would probably not call it either extremely elegant or super efficient... but it certainly works.